# How do I configure Hudson to run on port 80?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm setting up Hudson as an integration server that I expect other developers and stackholders to access. Rather than have to pass around urls with a specific port, I'd like to configure Hudson to listen on port 80.

The default port from installing Hudson as a service is 8080. I'd like to change this to 80, on a Server 2008 R2 or windows 7 machine that isn't running IIS or Apache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do the following to reconfigure the port :

- Edit hudson.xml (found in your hudson installation directory)

  - change the parameter string on line 44 to reference port 80 (--httpPort=8080 to --httpPort 80)
- Depending on what plugins you may have set up, there may be other references to the hudson url. Find these by doing a text search in the hudson directory on ':8080' and removing the port number.
- Disable the 'World Wide Web Publishing Service' service. By default, this service consumes port 80, which is the port we want to use.
- Verify that your machine is configured to accept an external connection on port 80 (ie, open a firewall port)
- Restart the Hudson service.

Comment: For those using Jenkins, it's jenkins.xml.